# Difficult in debugging app script

Tags: arrays, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

how to resolve google app scripting error: "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 16, file "Code")" when debugging the following script:

```
function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_("Still looking for Python Programming help");
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the sheet variable?

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Do `Logger.log(array2d);` to check the data is being set in the array.

It'll be because it cant find the sheet.

I sometimes had this error and had to rename the sheet and it worked. It's strange.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `getRange()` on a `null sheet` because in your context `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` return `null` (ie. there is no active spreadsheet)

More context could help to find a way to provide an active Spreadsheet to your function.

You can by instance open a spreadsheet with :

- `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)`
- `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`
- `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)`

And then set it active `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newActiveSpreadsheet)`
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

There is other ways to make a spreadsheet active, for example when a trigger is fired (ex. `notifyOnFormSubmit`).

To ensure you have an active spreadsheet, you can test `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` before using it :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if (spreadsheet) {
  Logger.log('spreadsheet url:' + spreadsheet.getUrl());
}
```